# PHP serialize / unserialize ERROR

Tags: php, arrays, database

i want to save an array in my database and want to turn it back to in array when I output it from my database.
For this I used the following code:

```
$string = base64_encode(serialize($_SESSION['warenkorb']));

$array = unserialize(base64_decode($zeile['b_warenkorb']));
```

I always get the following error:

```
Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 72 of 75 bytes
```

I used a multidimensional array for this.

I hope someone could help me. would be nice :)

Comment: Can you post the content of the `$_SESSION['warenkorb'];` variable?

Comment: The content with base64 is: YTozOntpOjA7YToyOntzOjEyOiJ3YXJlbmtvcmJfaWQiO3M6MToiNiI7czo1OiJtZW5nZSI7czoxOiIyIjt9aToxO2E6Mjp7czox without it is: a:3:{i:0;a:2:{s:12:"warenkorb_id";s:1:"6";s:5:"menge";s:1:"2";}i:1;a:2:{s:1

Comment: Its invalid serialization data. Check your data properly

Comment: Are you sure that the `b_warenkorb` column length is good enough? Maybe it truncate your contents.

Comment: @Federkun, that's a nice one...

Comment: @Federkun its a varchar with a content of 200 chars

Answer (score 2):

The solution is, that the column length wasnt long enough. I used 200 chars, but it needed many more.
Thanks @Federkun